# "sudo apt-get install xyz" command

Tags: linux, aptitude

Can someone explain what actions this command will perform?

> `sudo apt-get install xyz`

Comment: It's related to QT development. See also the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646232/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lfreetype-qt

Answer (score 18):

Indeed, lets break this down.

- **sudo** (some parameters): Instructs the operating system to execute the parameters as a command, but do so with administrative (usually *root*) privileges.
- **apt-get** (some parameters): Runs the package manager called *apt-get* on your machine. The parameters are a command for apt-get to run.
- **install xyz**: These parameters to apt-get instruct apt-get to find and install a package called *xyz*.

So, as a whole, this command attempts to find and install package/program *xyz* on your machine and does so as root if you are able to authenticate as such.

Answer (score 4):

Note: **"apt-get install"** will also install missing dependencies for the **xyz** package.

Answer (score 3):

for future reference, the man command can help with commands

just type

```
man *yourCommand*
```

or in your case

```
man sudo

man apt-get
```

Comment: A bit bofh'ish, but I like it!

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a ServerFault.com question than StackOverflow, but it instructs the package manager to install the xyz program.

sudo - do this as an administrative user
apt-get - the package management program
install - the instruction for the program
xyz - the program to install

Comment: And how can I see from what repository will the library be installed? My OS is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see the repository that would be used to install a package, use the following:

```
apt-get --print-uris install xyz
```

then answer "Y". The URIs will be printed, but the package won't be installed.

To see what repositories you have configured, look at this file `/etc/apt/sources.list` which can be edited (but you should probably use `System>Administration>Software Sources` to choose repositories.

Answer (score 1):

To see what versions of a package are available to be installed, and from what repository, try

```
apt-cache policy xyz
```

Comment: apt-cache policy doesn't need root privileges.